# Erro acessando uma struct

Tags: c, array, struct

Criei uma função para ler quantas horas o funcionário trabalhou na semana, contudo, tenho problemas em salvar efetivamente na memória do `struct`.

Chamando a função:

```
lerHoraExtra(&funcionario[i].horasExtra);
```

A função em si, só recebe a `struct` do funcionário e no laço for, o usuário deve adicionar quantas horas trabalhou na semana.

```
float lerHoraExtra(struct funcionario *func){
  int i,j;
  printf("Considere que a semana comece na segunda-feira(dia 1)\n");

    for(j=0; j<SEMANA; j++){
      printf("\nInforme quantas horas extra o funcionario fez no dia %d: ", j+1);
      scanf("%f", &func[i].horasExtra[j]);
  }
}
```

Contudo, quando realizo o cálculo e salvo no arquivo, não salva, tenho certeza que o erro está na função, porém não sei de que outro modo poderia fazer.

A `struct`:

```
typedef struct funcionario{
  int id;
  char nome[101];
  float horasTrab;
  float salarioHora;
  float horasExtra[SEMANA];
  float valorExtra;
}funcionario[TAM];
```

Comment: Esse `i` que apareceu do nada deve ser o problema. Você passou um elemento e depois acessa como *array*, não faz sentido.

Comment: Se removo o [i] da função, aparece o erro `[cquery] member reference type 'struct funcionario *' is a pointer; did you mean to use '->'?` e mesmo aplicando o ->, continuo com problemas

Comment: Quando remove algo que tinha colocado aleatoriamente no código o compilador diz exatamente qual é o erro e como consertar. Use o compilador a seu favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código tem alguns problemas e não vou falar de todos, mas seria isto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SEMANA 7
#define TAM 1

typedef struct {
    int id;
    char nome[101];
    float horasTrab;
    float salarioHora;
    float horasExtra[SEMANA];
    float valorExtra;
} Funcionario;

void lerHoraExtra(Funcionario *funcionario) {
    printf("Considere que a semana comece na segunda-feira(dia 1)\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < SEMANA; i++) {
        printf("\nInforme quantas horas extra o funcionario fez no dia %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%f", &funcionario->horasExtra[i]);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    Funcionario funcionarios[TAM];
    lerHoraExtra(&funcionarios[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < SEMANA; i++) printf("\n%f", funcionarios[0].horasExtra[i]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ex1TOY). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/jlulcrkq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/AccessMember.c).

Eu criei a variável com escopo local que é muito melhor que criar global. Usei o tipo definido, não faz sentido criá-lo e não usar. Essa variável tem um nome no plural porque é uma coleção de dados e não um dado só. Pode parecer besteira mas essas coisas ajudam dar o entendimento correto.

Não fiz um código para ser bem correto, apenas para funcionar e demonstrar como é.

Passei apenas o elemento que eu quero que a leitura seja feita. Isso não é a melhor forma de fazer, mas segui o que começou. Claro que no código real poderia estar em um laço e passar através da variável `i` pode fazer sentido.

É bom reforçar a ideia que está passando por referência apenas um elemento e não a coleção toda.

Aí eu mando fazer a leitura dos valores e guardo do campo de horas extras do elemento. Portanto eu devo acessar cada hora extra como um elemento de uma coleção, mas o objeto geral que vou acessar não pode ser como um *array* porque ele não é um *array*.

E preciso usar o operador certo quando o acesso é feito por referência e não por valor, então usei o `->` .

Precisa entender todos os mecanismos que está usando antes de usar. Fiz um exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável, que é o ideal para demostrar algo para outras pessoas.